# How to create a report with custom data and use that data in QWEB report?

Tags: pdf, report, odoo, qweb

i want to pass data to qweb report and print that data in report.

python code:

```
pdf = self.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf(self.ids, report_name, data={'test_variable': 'test_passed'})
```

report template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report id="my_module.report_id" model="my_module.report_model" string="Some Model Report" report_type="qweb-pdf" name="my_module.daily_report" file="my_module.daily_report_file" menu="False"/>
        <template id="my_module.daily_report">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h4>HEADER</h4>
                            <-- i want to see "test_passed" value below -->
                            <span t-esc="data.test_variable"/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

When i create a pdf, i don't see variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data using this code

```
from odoo import models, api

class ReportClassName(models.AbstractModel):
   _name = 'report.module_name.report_name'

   @api.model
   def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
      docargs = {
       'doc_ids': self.ids,
       'doc_model': self.model,
       'data': data,
      }
     return self.env['report'].render('module_name.report_name', docargs)
```

you can pass data as data by using this custom report.py for report and call this

```
<t t-esc="data"/>
```

in template to view data in qweb report.please refer this [link](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/qweb-reports-in-odoo-v10) for custom report creation using py and xml file.

In odoo11 or odoo 12 you can use get_report_values instead of render_html

```
@api.model
def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None): 
    docs = self.env['model.name'].browse(docids)
    return {
         'doc_ids': docids,
         'doc_model': 'model.name',
         'docs': docs,
         'lines': self.some_func(docs),
         'data': data,
    }
```

If data is some function call that function in lines and lines['field'] to get data in pdf

Comment: Thank you, but i need to pass variable in get_pdf method because i need pdf as an output.

Comment: odoo first renders a pdf record as html and then converts it to pdf with wkhtmltopdf. So it should work the same way

Comment: @TahirHan This method is used to pass data to pdf

Comment: Thanks for comments, according to your comments how can i convert the output of @Thayifkabir 's answer function to pdf? i checked it, it is also a string but outputs of get_pdf and render methods are different. encoding them with base64 gives different results.

Comment: @TahirHan If you re sing odoo11 or odoo12 the render_html was replaced with the function get_report_values

Comment: @Thayifkabir I am using odoo 10 :(

Comment: You can also use separate function to get data and pass in lines same as in odoo11 and call it in xml